# Issue about mark of probability of A given not B

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

P(A|BC) is same with this mark? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QePD.jpg)

Comment: What appears in the image probably means the conditional probability of A given _not_ B, i.e. given the complement of B.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean "Is $\mathsf P(A\mid\overline B)$ the same as $\mathsf P(A\mid B^\complement)~$?", then yes, the bar can be used to indicate complements, and is likely doing so in your image.